# My mint plant leaves are slightly yellowish and seems to be dropping. Does anyone know why is this so?

Tags: plant-health, mint

I bought my mint plant somewhere in January, but now I noticed the mint plant's stem are very long, and the leaves are slightly yellowish. The leaves are very fragile, and soft, not strong like they used to be. The plant also seem to be drooping slightly. What should I do?

Comment: It is likely that the long stems are the result of insufficient light. For the fragile leaves it would be easier if you could upload a picture so that we can see the plant and even the pot, otherwise there are too many possible answers.

Comment: Northern or Southern hemisphere? Plant is indoors or outdoors? In ground or potted? I'd guess at Northern, indoors, potted, and desperate for light, But I'm guessing, since you didn't mention these things.

Answer (score 1):

From the stem length detail, I would conclude that it's lack of light. If it's inside, mint likes morning sun but the afternoon sun can dry it out in the pot. Make sure it stays moist if inside.